# Does navigation bottom bar only works with Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, navigationbar

I'm trying to add navigation bottom bar with 4 activities(each activity has each layout xml files) to swith with tab the bottom bar. I saw some examples and tutorials, they implement navigation bottom bar with fragment activites. I have already made all activites(including google map), when I tried to switch FragmentActivity to Fragment, it causes lots of errors. 
SO, does navigation bottom bar only works with Fragment?